# Pig game runtime error

Tags: c, runtime-error

I was given this project to do in class. The task is to create a game of pig that uses a random number generator for dice rolls and declares a winner when a total of 100 is reached. I get a "fatal runtime error" but I can't give further information on the error due to the compiler I'm using.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

/* The diceroll function generates random numbers between 1 and 6 */
int diceroll (void) {
    int num = (rand() % 6) + 1;
    return num;
}

int player1 (void) { /* Function that handles the number generated by the diceroll func and returns number to main */
    int dice;
    int total;
    dice = diceroll();
    if (dice != 1) {
        total = total + dice;
        printf("you have rolled %d and your total is now %d \n", &dice, &total);
    } else {
        total = 0;
        printf("You have rolled a 1, your total for this turn has been reduced to 0 \n");
    }
}

int player2 (void) { /* Copy of player1 func with change of numbers */
    int dice;
    int total;
    dice = diceroll();
    if (dice != 1) {
        total = total + dice;
        printf("you have rolled %d and your total is now %d \n", &dice, &total);
    } else {
        total = 0;
        printf("You have rolled a 1, your total for this turn has been reduced to 0 \n");
    }
    return total;
}

int main (void) {
    int score1;
    int score2;
    char choice1;
    char choice2;
    int sum1;
    int sum2;

    while (score1 < 100 && score2 < 100) { /* Loop that runs until a player has won */
        do {
            printf("Player 1 do you want to roll y/n? \n");
            scanf(" %c ", &choice1);
            if (choice1 == 'y') {
                sum1 = sum1 + player1();
                score1 = sum1;
                printf("Your score is %d \n", &score1);
            } else if (choice1 == 'n') {
                score1 + 0;
                sum1 = 0;
                printf("Your score is %d \n", &score1);
            } else {
                printf("invalid, repeat");
            }
        } while (choice1 == 'y' || choice1 != 'y' && choice1 != 'n' || sum1 != 0);

        do {
            printf("Player 2 do you want to roll y/n? \n");
            scanf(" %c ", &choice2);
            if (choice2 == 'y') {
                sum2 = sum2 + player2();
                score2 = sum2;
                printf("Your score is %d \n", &score2);
            } else if (choice2 == 'n') {
                score2 + 0;
                sum2 = 0;
                printf("Your score is %d \n", &score2);
            } else {
                printf("invalid, repeat");
            }
        } while (choice2 == 'y' || choice2 != 'y' && choice2 != 'n' || sum2 != 0);
    }

    /* When a player has won, 1 of the following statements is displayed */

    if (score1 >= 100 && score2 < 100) {
        printf("Congrats player 1");   
    } else if (score2 >= 100 && score1 < 100) {
        printf("Congrats player 2");   
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: End outputs like the 'congrats' messages with newlines.   Decide what you do if both players score 100 or more; you shouldn't just silently exit.

Answer (score 1):

You're using `total` uninitialized in `player1` and `player2` functions. Initialize them in their respective declarations (i.e. `int total = 0;`).

The same is happening for `score1` and `score2` variables in `main` function.

Last thing, you need to be careful about the order of precedence in some conditionals depending your expected behavior. For example:

```
while (choice2 == 'y' || choice2 != 'y' && choice2 != 'n' || sum2 != 0)
```

Which one is applied first the `||` or the `&&`?

Comment: Hmm, these are issues, but would they cause runtime crashes?

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I see:

- `player1` doesn't have a `return total` statement at the end
- In `main`, `score1`, `score2`, `sum1`, and `sum2` should be initialized to 0.
- In your `printf` calls where you're printing out ints, pass the variables themselves, not their addresses, i.e. don't use `&`.  This is probably what's causing the crashes.
- `player1` and `player2` should probably have `total` as a parameter to the function instead of local variables.  You'll want to pass in `sum1` and `sum2` respectively.

Based on the order of operations, your `do .. while` conditional would look like this if you wanted to be explicit:

```
((choice1 == 'y') || ((choice1 != 'y') && (choice1 != 'n')) || (sum1 != 0))
```

I think this is what you intended, but it's better to add the parenthesis anyway to be more clear.

Comment: Thankyou for the response. I dont fully understand what you mean by pass in sum1 and sum2. could you possibly explain that further? please and thankyou.

Comment: After modifying `player1` and `player2` to each accept `int total` as a parameter, you want to call them as `player1(sum1)` and `player2(sum2)`.